# Why weren't the Titans visible when the Armored Titan broke through Wall Maria?

Tags: attack-on-titan

How come in the first episode when the Armored Titan breaks through Wall Maria, there aren't any Titans visible

> given that the wall is made of Titans?

When Eren battles the Female Titan later on

> the Titans in the wall are easily visible.

Was this due to the story having not developed to this point or is there another explanation?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It was noted later that the gate is the weakness of the walls. Why?

> Because there is no Hardened Titan inside, unlike the rest of the walls.

Which is why Colossal Titan targeted it in the first place. Because of this, when Armored Titan charges in, no Titan was shown inside the wall.

Comment: You are correct, the armored titan went through a gate, NOT the wall itself.

Comment: This. Since gates are the only movable part of wall, it might be rather expected, that there is no titan there.

Comment: Reread, was the gate, not the wall.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it's a combination of:

1. Not wanting to spoil later story developments, but failing to appropriately cover the wall with smoke, non-revealing frames (eg: show the wall at an angle where the inside guts would not be visible).
2. Lack of planning when it comes to the narrative.
3. Secret, yet undiscovered plot line wherein which we find out there are secret invisible titans everywhere (not serious).
4. Laziness.  Drawing more titans adds more work.

I'm pretty sure 2, is the reason why though.

Comment: Yeah, I'm feeling it's number 2 also

Comment: The Armored Titan charged through the gate, not the wall itself. It would make sense there are no titans in the gate itself.

Comment: The sides of the wall connecting to the gate were definitely damaged though @RFKomos

Comment: It was not large at all. It's entirely plausible that Titans were on either side of the hole in the walls and completely unseeable. http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-V4w-99h-6hY/VA3aPDlRqXI/AAAAAAAAEL4/gyU61mqxmBk/s1600/AttackTitanep139.jpg @DarthFutuza